# Add comments to HEAD Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, helper

Is there a view helper to add comments (not conditional comments) to the HEAD section of the page. I am using a layout approach.

Comment: Could you explain better. You want to change the comments from actions?

Comment: no...we have headScript, headLink view helpers in Zend.....so just thinking if there was anything similar to add comments.....i just added them with a place holder variable........You might be wondering what the comments are for.....they are for PageMaps which google would read

Answer (score 0):

On a couple of the view helpers supplied with Zend Framework you can use captureStart() and captureEnd() to grab comments. Not what it is designed for, but it works.

eg (in a view script):

```
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>
<!--some comment-->
<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd(); ?>
```

Then in your layout echo $this->headScript() in the head.

This is just proof of concept. Most of the head view helpers will throw an error if you try this. It only works with headScript and headStyle. Of the two I would use headStyle as good practice these days is to have the styles in the head and scripts in the footer. Ideally you can write your own view helper to do this specifically.